# How do I skip over the first two characters in each line to assign just the third to my array in c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file as follows:
6 1 C
6 2 S
6 3 R
6 4 R

this is only the first four lines. There is 90 of them divided into 3 sections of 30 (6, 7 and 8). I would like to only read in the character into my array.

This is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int MONTHS = 3;
const int DAYS = 30;

// Function definitions
void readFile(char daily[][DAYS], int size);
void showStats(char daily[], int days);

int main()
{

    char daily[MONTHS][DAYS];

    readFile(daily, MONTHS);

    //  Make sure we place the end message on a new line
    cout << endl;

    //  The following is system dependent.  It will only work on Windows
    system("PAUSE");

    /* 
    // A non-system dependent method is below
    char anyKey;
    cout << "Press any key to continue";
    cin >> anyKey;
    */
    return 0;
}

void readFile(char daily[][DAYS], int size)
{
        // open file.
        ifstream inputFile("RainOrShine.dat");
        if (!inputFile)
        {
                cout << "ERROR: cannot find/read file." << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cout << "Reading file...\n";

        // read data.
        for (int months = 0; months < size; months++)
        {
                for (int days = 0; days < DAYS; days++)
                {
                  inputFile >> daily[months][days];
                  cout << daily[months][days] << ", ";
                }
                cout << "\nDone with Row[" << (months);
                cout << "]...\n";
        }

        // close file.
        inputFile.close();
        cout << "Closing File...\n" << endl;
}

void showStats(char daily[], int days)
{
     //code
}
```

Currently it is looping through it and puts 30 elements like this in row 1 of my element:
6, 1, C, 6, 2, S, 6, 3, R, 6, 4, R, 6, 5, C, 6, 6, S, 6, 7, S, 6, 8, S, 6, 9, S, 6, 1, 0,

then grabs the next set like it for the 2nd and the same for the third. Should I be looking at a multi-dimensional array?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to read the third column, you can do this:

```
std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");

int dummy1, dummy2;
char c;

std::vector<char> v;

while (infile >> dummy1 >> dummy2 >> c)
{
    std::cout << "We got: '" << c << "'.\n";
    v.push_back(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
inputFile >> daily[months][days];
```

by

```
char tmp;
inputFile >> tmp >> tmp >> daily[months][days];
```